# Email responses prompt crowds Answer button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The Add Another Answer/Answer your Question button is floated to the left, causing the prompt to receive email notifications appear somewhat awkwardly to the right:

[image: email question offset]

I'm not positive it doesn't end up in the same position on other sides, but the prompt should at least be in line with the button vertically and spaced a little further to the right.

The `float: left;` on that prompt also causes weird things when you get errors on the ask form:

[image: oddly positioned self-answer checkbox]

Comment: With you pointing out some issues, I realize I've since started ignoring the bugs in layout and function we have here :( I've not had good response when posting bugs to the main meta - especially when using mobile safari. Thanks for the fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed.

[image]